# Compiling CUDA examples gives build error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cuda

I am running Windows 7 64bit, with Visual Studio 2008.  I installed the CUDA drivers and SDK. The SDK comes with quite a few examples including compiled executables and source code.  The compiled executables run wonderfully. When I open the vc90 solutions and go to build in Win32 configuration I get this error:

```
Error   1   fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\Release\bandwidthTest.cu.obj'    bandwidthTest   bandwidthTest
```

Build log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: bandwidthTest, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling with CUDA Build Rule...
1>"C:\CUDA\bin64\nvcc.exe"    -arch sm_10 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MT  " -I"C:\CUDA\include" -I"../../common/inc" -maxrregcount=32  --compile -o "Release\bandwidthTest.cu.obj" "c:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu" 
1>nvcc fatal   : Visual Studio configuration file '(null)' could not be found for installation at 'c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/bin/../..'
1>Linking...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\Release\bandwidthTest.cu.obj'
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\bandwidthTest\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>bandwidthTest - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I attempt to compile in x64 it doesn't build at all and just skips the project

```
1>------ Skipped Build: Project: bandwidthTest ------
1> 
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

I am new to C++, having been doing C# for a while.  I'm certain there is something small that I am missing, but any clues you could provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have x64 compiler installed. Then change project type to x64. I had the same problem when trying to compile 32bit cuda program with 64bit win7.

Also make sure you have added 64bit libs and includes to the search path.

Answer (score 2):

You're focusing on the wrong error message.

The .obj file doesn't exist because the nvcc compile step failed.

```
nvcc fatal   : Visual Studio configuration file '(null)' could not be found for installation at 'c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/bin/../..'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all the tools match. So if you have the 64-bit Visual Studio compiler installed then you should install the 64-bit version of the CUDA toolkit.

If you only have the 32-bit Visual Studio compiler, then you should be able to install the 32-bit CUDA toolkit. Ideally you would install all the 64-bit tools. Then you will be able to build both the 64-bit and 32-bit (cross-compile) examples.